# Config server and eureka server in same application: tries to connect to localhost:8761

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-config

I have a spring-boot application which I use to setup a `spring cloud config server` and a `eureka server` in development and testing environments.
Strangely the application always tries to connect to `localhost:8761`, even though I have `eureka.client.registerWithEureka` set to false.

How can I deactivate this?

The error:

```
ERROR 3144 --- [et_localhost-12] c.n.e.cluster.ReplicationTaskProcessor   : Network level connection to peer localhost; retrying after delay

com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to localhost:8761 timed out
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:187) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.netflix.eureka.cluster.DynamicGZIPContentEncodingFilter.handle(DynamicGZIPContentEncodingFilter.java:48) ~[eureka-core-1.4.10.jar:1.4.10]
    at com.netflix.discovery.EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.handle(EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.java:27) ~[eureka-client-1.4.10.jar:1.4.10]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:570) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.netflix.eureka.transport.JerseyReplicationClient.submitBatchUpdates(JerseyReplicationClient.java:116) ~[eureka-core-1.4.10.jar:1.4.10]
    at com.netflix.eureka.cluster.ReplicationTaskProcessor.process(ReplicationTaskProcessor.java:71) ~[eureka-core-1.4.10.jar:1.4.10]
    at com.netflix.eureka.util.batcher.TaskExecutors$BatchWorkerRunnable.run(TaskExecutors.java:187) [eureka-core-1.4.10.jar:1.4.10]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_92]
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to localhost:8761 timed out
```

My only class looks like this:

```
@EnableEurekaServer
@EnableConfigServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

The `application.yml`:

```
server:
  port: 8888

eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
  server:
    waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty: 0
    renewal-percent-threshold: 0.49

security:
  basic:
    enabled: true
  user:
    password: mypassword


spring:
  jmx:
    default-domain: ${spring.application.name}
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://example.com/myrepo.git
          username: username
          password: password
          clone-on-start: true
          search-paths: '{application},{application}/{profile}'

endpoints:
  jmx:
    domain: ${spring.application.name}
    unique-names: true
```

In the `bootstrap.yml` I have only the application name set.

Versions:

spring-cloud-netflix-eureka: `1.1.6`,
spring-cloud-config-server: `1.1.3`

Comment: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-eureka-server.html#spring-cloud-eureka-server-standalone-mode

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Could you try to change your configuration like below

```
eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8888/eureka
```

You specify `server.port: 8888`. So your eureka is running on 8888 port. But you didn't specify any service-url for eureka. So I think that your eureka server is trying to replicate to localhost:8761 because it's default and you didn't specify service-url for eureka.

Comment: Hi yongsung.yoon. That works, but it is not what I am trying to do. I'd like to turn off replication to localhost:8888 completely. How can I do that?

Comment: Does replication still happen ? AFAIK, if you add properties like above, replication will not be happened. Because eureka checks url of service-url and compare it with hostname of itself. if it is url for itself, this node will be excluded for replica nodes.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I missed the `/eureka` in my configuration. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

For me, below properties that worked for me.

```
eureka.client.registerWithEureka= false
eureka.client.fetchRegistry= false
eureka.server.maxThreadsForPeerReplication=0
```

Comment: This worked! The service-url attribute didn't have any impact

Answer (score 5):

Please Use 8761 port for your Eureka server as below.

```
server:
  port: 8761
eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
```

Here we’re configuring an application port – 8761 is the default one for Eureka servers. We are telling the built-in Eureka Client not to register with ‘itself’, because our application should be acting as a server.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that eureka tries to connect to itself despite the below settings:

```
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false 
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
```

you have two options to fix that 1-Keep the default port of eureka 2-Add below to your `application.properties` of your eureka server `eureka.server.maxThreadsForPeerReplication=0`