# spring-boot microservice fails to register to eureka

Tags: java, spring-boot, netflix-eureka

I have setup where I'm using spring boot + kafka + eureka + zuul + spring cloud config. However, spring boot service called feedback-service-acceptance fails to register to eureka. Don't know why... Albeit, other services such as zuulservice and configserver registering themselves fine.

when I try to go via zuul url **/api/feedback** i.e

```
http://192.168.99.100:<port>/api/feedback/
```

using payload as

```
{"name": "test", "subject": "test", "email": "test@test.com", "message": "test"}
```

I get an error:

```
zuulserver_1                 | com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error
zuulserver_1                 |  at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.handleException(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:191) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.0.RELEASE]
zuulserver_1                 |  at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.forward(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:166) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.0.RELEASE]
zuulserver_1                 |  at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.run(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:114) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.0.RELEASE]
zuulserver_1                 |  at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter.runFilter(ZuulFilter.java:117) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
zuulserver_1                 |  at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:193) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
zuulserver_1                 |  at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.runFilters(FilterProcessor.java:157) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
zuulserver_1                 |  at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.route(FilterProcessor.java:118) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
zuulserver_1                 |  at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulRunner.route(ZuulRunner.java:96) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
zuulserver_1                 |  at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.route(ZuulServlet.java:116) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
zuulserver_1                 |  at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.service(ZuulServlet.java:81) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar!/:1.3.1]
zuulserver_1                 |  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:165) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
zuulserver_1                 |  at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulController.handleRequest(ZuulController.java:44) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.0.RELEASE]
zuulserver_1                 |  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
zuulserver_1                 |  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
zuulserver_1                 |  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
zuulserver_1                 |  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
zuulserver_1                 |  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
zuulserver_1                 |  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
zuulserver_1                 |  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
zuulserver_1                 |  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
zuulserver_1                 |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
zuulserver_1                 |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
zuulserver_1                 |  at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
zuulserver_1                 |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
zuulserver_1                 |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
zuulserver_1                 |  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.3.RELEASE]
zuulserver_1                 |  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
zuulserver_1                 |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
zuulserver_1                 |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
zuulserver_1                 |  at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
zuulserver_1                 |  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
zuulserver_1                 |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
zuulserver_1                 |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
zuulserver_1                 |  at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
zuulserver_1                 |  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
zuulserver_1                 |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
zuulserver_1                 |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
zuulserver_1                 |  at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
zuulserver_1                 |  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
zuulserver_1                 |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
zuulserver_1                 |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
zuulserver_1                 |  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:117) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.3.RELEASE]
zuulserver_1                 |  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:106) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.3.RELEASE]
zuulserver_1                 |  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
zuulserver_1                 |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
zuulserver_1                 |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
zuulserver_1                 |  at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
zuulserver_1                 |  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE]
zuulserver_1                 |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
zuulserver_1                 |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
zuulserver_1                 |  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
zuulserver_1                 |  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
zuulserver_1                 |  at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
zuulserver_1                 |  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
zuulserver_1                 |  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
zuulserver_1                 |  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
zuulserver_1                 |  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
zuulserver_1                 |  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
zuulserver_1                 |  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
zuulserver_1                 |  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
zuulserver_1                 |  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
zuulserver_1                 |  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
zuulserver_1                 |  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
zuulserver_1                 |  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
zuulserver_1                 |  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar!/:9.0.16]
zuulserver_1                 |  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
zuulserver_1                 | Caused by: com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have available server for client: feedbackacceptanceservice
zuulserver_1                 |  at com.netflix.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerContext.getServerFromLoadBalancer(LoadBalancerContext.java:483) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.3.0.jar!/:2.3.0]
zuulserver_1                 |  at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:184) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.3.0.jar!/:2.3.0]
zuulserver_1                 |  at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:180) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.3.0.jar!/:2.3.0]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap.call(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:94) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap.call(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:42) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber$1.call(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:127) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.internal.schedulers.TrampolineScheduler$InnerCurrentThreadScheduler.enqueue(TrampolineScheduler.java:73) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.internal.schedulers.TrampolineScheduler$InnerCurrentThreadScheduler.schedule(TrampolineScheduler.java:52) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber.onNext(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:79) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber.onNext(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:45) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$WeakSingleProducer.request(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:276) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:209) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$JustOnSubscribe.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:138) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$JustOnSubscribe.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:129) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10423) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10390) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.blockForSingle(BlockingObservable.java:443) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.single(BlockingObservable.java:340) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.executeWithLoadBalancer(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:112) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.3.0.jar!/:2.3.0]
zuulserver_1                 |  at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.support.AbstractRibbonCommand.run(AbstractRibbonCommand.java:186) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.0.RELEASE]
zuulserver_1                 |  at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.support.AbstractRibbonCommand.run(AbstractRibbonCommand.java:51) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.0.RELEASE]
zuulserver_1                 |  at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:302) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.18.jar!/:1.5.18]
zuulserver_1                 |  at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:298) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.18.jar!/:1.5.18]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:46) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10423) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10390) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.internal.operators.BlockingOperatorToFuture.toFuture(BlockingOperatorToFuture.java:51) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.toFuture(BlockingObservable.java:410) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
zuulserver_1                 |  at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand.queue(HystrixCommand.java:378) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.18.jar!/:1.5.18]
zuulserver_1                 |  at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand.execute(HystrixCommand.java:344) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.18.jar!/:1.5.18]
zuulserver_1                 |  at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.forward(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:161) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.0.RELEASE]
zuulserver_1                 |  ... 64 common frames omitted
zuulserver_1                 |
zuulserver_1                 | 2019-04-11 07:35:53.647 DEBUG 92 --- [nio-5555-exec-1] c.i.zuulsvr.filters.ResponseFilter       : Adding the correlation id to the outbound headers.
zuulserver_1                 | 2019-04-11 07:35:53.665 DEBUG 92 --- [nio-5555-exec-1] c.i.zuulsvr.filters.ResponseFilter       : Completing outgoing request for /error.
zuulserver_1                 | 2019-04-11 07:37:03.411 DEBUG 92 --- [nio-5555-exec-2] c.i.zuulsvr.filters.TrackingFilter       : preinterview-correlation-id generated in tracking filter: 41ce6308-3cf5-41e0-b214-83bb08038085.
zuulserver_1                 | 2019-04-11 07:37:03.424 DEBUG 92 --- [nio-5555-exec-2] c.i.zuulsvr.filters.TrackingFilter       : Processing incoming request for /api/feedback/.
zuulserver_1                 | 2019-04-11 07:37:03.439  WARN 92 --- [nio-5555-exec-2] o.s.c.n.z.f.r.s.AbstractRibbonCommand    : The Hystrix timeout of 41000ms for the command feedbackacceptanceservice is set lower than the combination of the Ribbon read and connect timeout, 800000ms.
zuulserver_1                 | 2019-04-11 07:37:03.472  WARN 92 --- [nio-5555-exec-2] o.s.c.n.z.filters.post.SendErrorFilter   : Error during filtering
zuulserver_1                 |
```

I'm using

Java 11, Docker with windows 8.1 & docker-compose
Intellij IDEA 2018.3.5

What have I tried so far...

```
https://memorynotfound.com/spring-cloud-eureka-service-discovery-client-server-example/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43247458/config-server-and-eureka-server-in-same-application-tries-to-connect-to-localho

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/509

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/2910
```

excerpt from maven dependencies

```
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
</dependencies>
```

What I expect:

I want to access service via zuul url

P.S

in this project

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

and

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>Greenwich.RELEASE</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

Sorry for awkward formatting. I'm terrible at it.

Answer (score 1):

After 48 hours of effort I posted a question to stackowerflow... after few more hours...
I found a solution of why the service failed to register itself to an eureka server.

So... From the beginning...

1. In order for zuul to access a service in this situation the service itself has to be registered to eureka server via auto-discovery capability. And so, this stack trace means
   that there are no service instances registered to an eureka or in other cases that zuul is not capable in seeing the service or interacting with the service.
2. For some unknown reason explained here (https://github.com/Netflix/zuul/issues/532)
   (missing ribbon-eureka issue)

replacing

```
`<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        **<dependency>**
            **<groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>**
            **<artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>**
        **</dependency>**
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
</dependencies>`
```

with

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        **<dependency>**
            **<groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>**
            **<artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>**
        **</dependency>**
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
</dependencies>
```

solved my issue

P.S

replace * with a bold font and ignore ``=]